# Unity Character Controller animation problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I just started my adventure with unity and I got stuck.

I need to make my character turn on animation walk when I press "W" and when there is no any key pressed stop and do Idle animation for being not moved (Sorry for my english I'm not a native speaker) and then when I press space char should jump and use jump anim my char actually move and jump but repeat only one animation even when I don't press any key.

Further, I want to make Climbing, Ledge Climb, character falling from the edge, etc smth like in Assassin's Creed. I want to animation play on keypress.[I just start to figure it out using transition but still luck of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sdiP.png)

I'm not sure what should I change, need a help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float walkSpeed = 20;
    public float runSpeed = 40;
    public float gravity = -80;
    public float jumpHeight = 15;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float airControlPercent;

    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.2f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;

    public float speedSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float speedSmoothVelocity;
    float currentSpeed;
    float velocityY;

    Animator animator;
    Transform cameraT;
    CharacterController controller;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        cameraT = Camera.main.transform;
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // input
        Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        Vector2 inputDir = input.normalized;
        bool running = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

        Move(inputDir, running);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
        }
        // animator
        float animationSpeedPercent = ((running) ? currentSpeed / runSpeed : currentSpeed / walkSpeed * .5f);
        animator.SetFloat("speedPercent", animationSpeedPercent, speedSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime);

    }

    void Move(Vector2 inputDir, bool running)
    {
        if (inputDir != Vector2.zero)
        {
            float targetRotation = Mathf.Atan2(inputDir.x, inputDir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cameraT.eulerAngles.y;
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation, ref turnSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(turnSmoothTime));
        }

        float targetSpeed = ((running) ? runSpeed : walkSpeed) * inputDir.magnitude;
        currentSpeed = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currentSpeed, targetSpeed, ref speedSmoothVelocity, GetModifiedSmoothTime(speedSmoothTime));

        velocityY += Time.deltaTime * gravity;
        Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * currentSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        currentSpeed = new Vector2(controller.velocity.x, controller.velocity.z).magnitude;

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            velocityY = 0;
        }

    }

    void Jump()
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            float jumpVelocity = Mathf.Sqrt(-2 * gravity * jumpHeight);
            velocityY = jumpVelocity;
        }
    }

    float GetModifiedSmoothTime(float smoothTime)
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {
            return smoothTime;
        }

        if (airControlPercent == 0)
        {
            return float.MaxValue;
        }
        return smoothTime / airControlPercent;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set up transitions conditions in your animator?

Comment: I added but still won't work as I want

Comment: Can i see the conditions on your transition? are you sure about the value of speedPercent?

Comment: I'm not sure of value I don't know what should be the proper value give me sec I will upload it

Comment: https://ibb.co/56TD7Nb

Comment: so i see you are using walkspeed as the condition but since you set it to 20 in the animator controller and never change it in your code it will always be true. You should use the speedPercent since its the value you are changing. Check if the exiting transition of the run animation also have conditions and that they are correct. Also check on your animation that the loop box is checked so it loop the animation

Comment: I'm not sure what value should I use cause SpeedPercent its from 0-1 and its slowing animation maybe I should exchange range from 1-10 and this will change smth I'm not sure.

Comment: what do you mean by slowing the animation? isnt the value only use to makes transition?

Comment: When I change value of speedpercent animation look like slow motions , yes

Comment: Maybe try to uncheck Has Exit Time on all The transitions(it will transit from one state to another faster). So just to be sure after reading again all this discussion, When you say that it only repeats one animation, do you mean it only do the idle animation? or if you try to jump it will jump once and never do it again?

Comment: hi I worked on somthing maybe its less optimilaized but work somhow there is one trouble with code cause still animaton won't stopw when I dont press any key link to code its to long to paste https://textuploader.com/1klai

Comment: This is because instead of using the animator controller(or in addition i would say), you are using `animator.Play("walk");` to start the walk animation but you are not stopping it anywhere so this is why it probably keeps walking even when you are not touching any buttons. I would suggest to debug your animator controller since it is clearer than hardcoded animation. You can debug it easily by Opening your animator controller,pressing play, click on your character that has the animator controller in your hierarchy, you will now see which state is being executed.

Comment: Check that every state has the right animation, the animation set to loop. if the conditions are not right, you will see that it plays the wrong state and it will show you if it gets stuck somewhere

Comment: The trouble was with conditions it was not declared in key what State will break the loop and start another I created new code more complicated but less chaotic

Comment: good if you found out what the problem was, is it working as intended now?

Comment: yes it all working I made some mistake and I started again. there is still some trouble but it work somehow